# Taking some part of an xml file with python

Tags: python, xml, xpath

I am really new to Python and I have the following `.xml` file:

```
<A>
  <B>
    <C>NUM123456</C>
    <D>
      <E>123</E>
      <F>Spam</F>
        <G>Apple</G>
    </D>
    <D>
      <E>456</E>
      <F>Egg</F>
        <G>Orange</G>
    </D>
    <D>
      <E>789</E>
      <F>Bacon</F>
        <G>Strawberry</G>
    </D>
    <D>
      <E>0AB</E>
      <F>Cheese</F>
        <G>Cherry</G>
    </D>
  </B>
</A>
```

I am trying to take just some part of it so that the new `.xml` file would be:

```
<A>
  <B>
    <C>NUM123456</C>
    <D>
      <E>456</E>
      <F>Egg</F>
        <G>Orange</G>
    </D>
    <D>
      <E>0AB</E>
      <F>Cheese</F>
        <G>Cherry</G>
    </D>
  </B>
</A>
```

I am trying to use the `.xpath`, but it will only start taking writing the new `.xml` file once it found the distinct node. In other words, node `<A> <B>` and `<C>` are not included in the new `.xml` file. Can anybody help?

Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate of this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2666436/xml-remove-child-node-of-a-node

Comment: The output on that one does not begin on new line.

Comment: Did you read the answer there? You could do `tree.listall('D')` and loop through the results to find the node you want to remove. I also don't know what you mean by "output" and "new line". You load the xml, remove the nodes you want to remove, and save to a different filename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put in the right criteria--I based this filter on the text values from your examples:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from xml.etree import ElementTree
import sys
tree = ElementTree.ElementTree()
tree.parse(sys.stdin)
b = tree.find("B")
for e in b.getiterator("D"):
    if e.find("E").text in ["123", "789"]: 
        b.remove(e)
tree.write(sys.stdout)
```

Run it like this:

> ./parse.py < file.xml

to get your desired output.

Comment: How do you do pretty_print on this?