# Python - replace root element of one xml file with another root element without its children

Tags: python, xml, parsing, element, elementtree

I have one xml file that looks like this, XML1:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<report>
</report>
```

And the other one that is like this,
XML2:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<report attrib1="blabla" attrib2="blabla" attrib3="blabla" attrib4="blabla" attrib5="blabla" >
    <child1>  
        <child2> 
            ....
        </child2>
    </child1>
</report>
```

I need to replace and put root element of XML2 without its children, so XML1 looks like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<report attrib1="blabla" attrib2="blabla" attrib3="blabla" attrib4="blabla" attrib5="blabla">
</report>
```

Currently my code looks like this but it won't remove children but put whole tree inside:

```
source_tree = ET.parse('XML2.xml')
source_root = source_tree.getroot()

report = source_root.findall('report') 

for child in list(report):
     report.remove(child)
     source_tree.write('XML1.xml', encoding='utf-8', xml_declaration=True)
```

Anyone has ide how can I achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [XML: remove child node of a node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2666436/xml-remove-child-node-of-a-node)

Comment: Unfortunately noup, because here he knows what are tags of children, but in my case they are changing, so this second iteration bars = foo.findall('bar') won't work in my situation

Comment: You just need to copy the `attrib` from **2** to **1**. See my answer.

Comment: recursively iterate over xml: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21074361/how-to-recursively-iterate-over-xml-tags-in-python-using-elementtree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below (just copy *attrib*)

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


xml1 = '''<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<report>
</report>'''

xml2 = '''<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<report attrib1="blabla" attrib2="blabla" attrib3="blabla" attrib4="blabla" attrib5="blabla" >
    <child1>  
        <child2> 
        </child2>
    </child1>
</report>'''

root1 = ET.fromstring(xml1)
root2 = ET.fromstring(xml2)

root1.attrib = root2.attrib

ET.dump(root1)
```

output

```
<report attrib1="blabla" attrib2="blabla" attrib3="blabla" attrib4="blabla" attrib5="blabla">
</report>
```

Comment: It's a such a fine solution, but I keep getting: ParseError
not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 2

Comment: If you copy & paste my solution - do you get any error? Please explain what you do.

Comment: I just put  root1 = ET.fromstring(xml1) and replace xml1 with whole path to the file like this ('C:/myPc/blabla/xml1.xml') and get error on that line

Comment: now I have managed to get it running, but attribute value is only printed in my console, not actually copied in file

Comment: You better share the code since I do not understand what the problem is.

Comment: Ok will edit now

Comment: @John, to save edited XML to file you need .... to save XML to file. [`root.write()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree.write)

Answer (score 0):

So here is working code:

```
source_tree = ET.parse('XML2.xml')
source_root = source_tree.getroot()

dest_tree = ET.parse('XML1.xml')
dest_root = dest_tree.getroot()

dest_root.attrib = source_root.attrib
dest_tree.write('XML1.xml', encoding='utf-8', xml_declaration=True)
```